# Filtering date in Redshift by date stored as a string

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

The below works as a filter. But I don't understand why.

We are taking column "valid_from" (with format 2019-06-20 00:00:00.0) and then converting it to a string and filtering by this (so we are filtering by a string). However, valid_from is in date/time format and not string so why does filtering by a string give results?

```
SELECT * from capacity_planning

WHERE TO_CHAR(valid_from, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = '23/06/2019'
```

Similarly, I've seen filters like:

```
where event_date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31';
```

But again, in such cases the dates being filtered for are strings?

Comment: The `BETWEEN` example should work, since the date format will be automatically converted to a string for the comparison.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly, you are saying we are filtering for a string. But my question is why does this work when the data in the column we are filtering (event_date) is not string format?

Comment: Redshift (and SQL in general) automatically converts the date into a string for comparison purposes. It is effectively saying: `event_date::text BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-31'`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, does the above mean using TO_DATE in a WHERE filter is pointless and irrelevant? e.g. if you do WHERE ship_date = TO_DATE('02/01/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'). Can there ever be any use for this? Or is it pointless since the date will be converter back to string?

Comment: The `TO_DATE()` function can be used to convert a string into a `DATE`. This is important where the date is ambiguous. For example, if a text field contains `5/6/2020`, is it 5-Jun, or 6-May? The preferred date format is to follow ISO standards, eg `2020-06-05`. Comparing a date field against an ISO text field, the comparison works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

this should work (just tried it )

```
   SELECT * from capacity_planning
   where event_date >= '2018-01-31' and event_date < '2018-01-01'
```

make sure you consider other possible causes

Comment: That would return an empty result, since the date ranges are not overlapping.